# libfann undefined symbol

Tags: fann

I'm install libfunn on my Ubuntu 11.10 and when I run example from "example" directory I get error.

Compile:

gcc  simple_train.c -o simple_train -lfann -lm

when execute:

./simple_train

Max epochs   500000. Desired error: 0.0010000000.

./simple_train: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libfann.so.2: undefined symbol: exp

How to Fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reinstall the library. You have installed it from Ubuntu repository or from source ?